# how to read PC information with DM script

Tags: dm-script

I want to release a DM script tied to a specific PC. GMS license won't work because free license has a common license ID,

```
"GATAN_FREE"
```

How can I insert a secret code to give error message when the script runs on a different machine? 
I am thinking to use computer name or username. Is there a way to read Windows system variables? If using

```
LaunchExternalProcessAsync(callString)
```

to launch DOS command "echo -username", how to catch the output? 
Any solution or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Nice thinking.
The trick with `LaunchExternalProcess` is to create some useful string which can be 'executed'. You can try various applications with their own command-line parameters.

---

In the most general situation, you can create a dummy-batch file and execute it. (Provided you have read/write access on the computer!)

As the `LaunchExternalProcess` also returns the exit code from the launched process, you can at least pass back one integer variable directly. Otherwise, you need to have the batch file save to a file and have DM read that file.

```
// Temporary batch file creation
    string batchPath = "C:\\Dummy.bat"
    string batchText

    string auxFilePath = "C:\\tmp_dummy.txt"
    batchText += "dir *.* >> " + auxFilePath + "\n"
    batchText += "exit 999" + "\n"

// Ensure no files exist...
    if ( DoesFileExist(auxFilePath) )
        DeleteFile(auxFilePath)

    if ( DoesFileExist(batchPath) )
        DeleteFile(batchPath)

// Write the batch file....
    number fileID = CreateFileForWriting(batchPath)
    WriteFile(fileID,batchText)
    CloseFile(fileID)

// Call the batch file and retrieve its exit code
    number kTimeOutSec = 5      // Prevent freezing of DM if something in the batch file is wrong
    number exitCode = LaunchExternalProcess( batchPath, kTimeOutSec ) 

// Do something with the results
    Result( "\n Exit value of batch was:" + exitCode )
    if ( DoesFileExist(auxFilePath) )
    {
        string line
        fileID = OpenFileForReading(auxFilePath)
        ReadFileLine( fileID, line )
        CloseFile(fileID)
        Result("\n First line of auxiliary file:" + line )
    }

// Ensure no files exist...
    if ( DoesFileExist(auxFilePath) )
        DeleteFile(auxFilePath)

    if ( DoesFileExist(batchPath) )
        DeleteFile(batchPath)
```

Comment: Thanks BmyGuest! Yes, writing the data out to a file gives the full access to DM script to the output. Good trick.

Answer (score 1):

> This is not a direct answer to your question, but to the overall goal you've mentioned.

An alternative "DM only" solution for restricting script access would be to use the persistent tags of the application itself! (These are stored in the preferences of the application.)

---

```
string tagPath = "MyScripts:LicensedComputer"
string installPW = "password"                   

string mayLoadPassCode = ""
GetPersistentStringNote( tagPath, mayLoadPassCode )
if ( mayLoadPassCode != installPW )
{
    string pw
    if ( !GetString( "Forbidden.\n Enter password:", pw, pw ) )
        exit(0)

    if ( pw != installPW )
        Throw( "Invalid password." )

    SetPersistentStringNote( tagPath, pw )  
}

OKDialog( "You may use my script..." )
```

Obviously this isn't the most secure lock-out, as any user could set the tag manually as well, but as long as the tag-path is "secret" and the password remains "secret" (i.e. you don't share the script in source code) it is reasonably 'save'.

In a similar way, you could make your script write a specific "license" file to the computer and check for that each time. The advantage is, that deleting/resetting the DM preference file would not affect this.